# tcpdump can't open file: permission denied (linux)

Tags: linux, tcpdump

I set all filters for Tcpdump in a config file, but when I run this command:

```
sudo tcpdump  -i any -w "./mypcap.pcap" -F "myfilters.txt"
```

I get permission denied although my file has rwx for users, groups, and others. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you're not allowed to "sudo tcpdump" ?

Answer (score 2):

You're probably in a directory that can't be written to, such as `/proc`, or an NFS mounted directory with `root_squash`. Change to a writable directory and try again, or direct your output file to a writable directory.

Comment: I changed my directory to drwxrwxrwx but still the same problem. It can be that there is a specific tcpdump permission problem on linux?

Comment: What is your directory's filesystem?

Comment: Filesystem:/dev/sda2 type:ext4

Answer (score 2):

This is an apparmor bug.  It supposedly works in `/tmp` and `/root`, but not for me.  A workaround is to run it with a specific apparmor profile:

```
aa-exec -p unconfined tcpdump -w file.pcap
```